# Toggle the display of a table echod from php in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table created in php that contains rows of customer information, with an additional row containing notes about each customer.

I would like a button above the table that when clicked will show or hide the notes row of each customer. So far my code doesn't seem to produce anything, I create the table here:

```
echo "<table id='listTable' border='1' cellpadding='10' class='listTable'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Company Name</th> <th>Telephone</th> <th>Alt/ Telephone</th>   <th>Address </th>  <th>Town</th>  <th>Postcode</th>  <th></th>   <th></th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
    for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
    {
            // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
            if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
            echo "<tr class='main'>";
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'First_Name') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Surname') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Company_Name') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Telephone') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Alt_Telephone') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'line_1') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'town') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'postcode') . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">View</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">Delete</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="archive.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">archive</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="NewJob.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '">New Job</a></td>';
            echo "</tr class='notes'>"; 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'notes') . '</td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 

    }
    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
```

and Have the following Javascript at the top of my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Records</title>

<script language="Javascript">
var rows = $('table.listTable tr.notes');

$('#showNotes').click(function() {
    var showN = rows.filter('.showN').show();
    rows.not( showN ).hide();
});

</script>
</head>
```

With the Toggle button created further down

```
<button id="showNotes">Toggle Notes</button>
```

When I click the button nothing is happening

Comment: You have your class in the closing tag of your `<tr class='main'>` -> `echo "</tr class='notes'>";`. Is this a typo? It should be in the next line/row -> `echo "<tr class='notes'>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add class `notes` to close tag `</tr>`.

You have:

```
echo "</tr class='notes'>"; 
echo "<tr>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "<tr class='notes'>";
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showNotes').click(function() {
      $('#listTable tr.notes').toggle();
  });
});
```

---

Now some remarks about your code:

1. Use `mysqli_*`, `mysql_*` is deprecated.
2. If you're using HTML in echo maybe try `'` for it: `echo '<tr class="notes">'` looks better I think.
3. Use prepared statements: [mysqli.prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
4. Check this out (against your `for` loop): [mysqli-stmt.fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the script in document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showNotes').click(function() {
      var showN = rows.filter('.showN').show();
      rows.not( showN ).hide();
  });
});
```